# dynamically scan dir and include any .conf file found and add them to httpd.conf

Tags: httpd.conf

i want to make a somewhat dynamic subdomain thing for my members.

I looked into PHP, which didn't really meet all my requirements.

alos htaccess wasn't right for me either.

the only problem is that i need "real" subdomain but because each subomain can point to a diff DocumentRoot then I need PHP to open up a new .conf file and append the VirtualHost information.

I was thinking that since in PHP there is the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator()` which can used to include files like this

```
$cf = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(dirname(__DIR__) . DS . "configuration");


    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
        if ($di->getFilename() != "." && $di->getFilename() != ".." && $di->getFilename() != "include.php") {
            require_once $filename;
        }
    }
```

is there a similar thing I can include in the httpd.conf file to include all the .conf files say in a folder called /myConfs

this way I can use PHP to make a new .conf file and inject the custom DocumentRoots and save it to /myConfs/user1.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good ol' [`Include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include) should do the trick:

```
Include /myConfs/
```

Comment: really, that will include everything in there that directory???

Comment: Yup.  Or, `Include /myConfs/*.conf`, if you just want files ending with `.conf`

Comment: would i need to restart apache every time i make a new .conf file?

Comment: Apache doesn't look for new config without some prompting, but a `reload` will probably fit your needs without doing a full service restart.

Comment: `service httpd restart`, is that the same as the reload your speaking off?

Comment: That'll restart the service completely, causing a bit of downtime.  `service httpd reload`, or `/etc/init.d/httpd reload` should be what you want from a graceful config reload.